# What is the most secure method for uploading a file?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

The company I work for has recently been hit with many header injection and file upload exploits on the sites we host and while we have fixed the problem with respect to header injection attacks, we have yet to get the upload exploits under control.

I'm trying to set up a plug-and-play-type series of upload scripts to use in-house that a designer can copy into their site's structure, modify a few variables, and have a ready-to-go upload form on their site. We're looking to limit our exposure as much as possible (we've already shut down fopen and shell commands).

I've searched the site for the last hour and found many different answers dealing with specific methods that rely on outside sources. What do you all think is the best script-only solution that is specific enough to use as a reliable method of protection? Also, I'd like to keep the language limited to PHP or pseudo-code if possible.

**Edit:** I've found my answer (posted below) and, while it does make use of the shell command exec(), if you block script files from being uploaded (which this solution does very well), you won't run into any problems.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The best solution, IMHO, is to put the directory containing the uploaded files outside of the "web" environment and use a script to make them downloadable. In this way, even if somebody uploads a script it can not be executed by calling it from the browser and you don't have to check the type of the uploaded file.

Comment: Yes, and placing that directory in a special noexec mounted partition is even better

Comment: Make the partition nosuid also.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the safest method but, for my particular situation the answer I've posted below is what works for me.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic noexec is **not** for security; from man page: """ Note: This option was not designed as a security feature and no guarantee is made that it will prevent malicious code execution;"""

Comment: @GoodPerson While it wasn't designed as one, it's certainly a useful approach as a defense in depth measure. Check out http://serverfault.com/questions/72356/how-useful-is-mounting-tmp-noexec

Answer (score 79):

1. **Allow only authorized users to upload a file.** You can add a captcha as well to hinder primitive bots.
2. First of all, **set the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in your upload form**, and set the **maximum file `size` and `count` on the server** as well.

   ```
   ini_set('post_max_size', '40M'); //or bigger by multiple files
   ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '40M');
   ini_set('max_file_uploads', 10);
   ```

   Do size check by the uploaded files:

   ```
   if ($fileInput['size'] > $sizeLimit)
       ; //handle size error here
   ```
3. You should **use `$_FILES` and [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276835/php-move-uploaded-file-why-is-it-important)** to put your uploaded files into the right directory, or if you want to process it, then check with `is_uploaded_file()`. (These functions exist to prevent *file name injections* caused by `register_globals`.)

   ```
   $uploadStoragePath = '/file_storage';
   $fileInput = $_FILES['image'];

   if ($fileInput['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
       ; //handle upload error here, see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

   //size check here

   $temporaryName = $fileInput['tmp_name'];
   $extension = pathinfo($fileInput['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   //mime check, chmod, etc. here

   $name = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)); //true random id

   move_uploaded_file($temporaryName, $uploadStoragePath.'/'.$name.'.'.$extension);
   ```

   Always **generate a random id instead of using the original file name**.
4. Create a **new *subdomain*** for example http://static.example.com or at least a new directory outside of the `public_html`, for the uploaded files. This *subdomain* or directory **should not execute any file**. Set it in the server config, or set [in a **`.htaccess` file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932756/disable-all-cgi-php-perl-for-a-directory-using-htaccess) by the directory.

   ```
       SetHandler none
       SetHandler default-handler
       Options -ExecCGI
       php_flag engine off
   ```

   Set it [**with `chmod()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828172/how-do-i-secure-a-web-servers-image-upload-directory) as well.

   ```
       $noExecMode = 0644;
       chmod($uploadedFile, $noExecMode);
   ```

   Use `chmod()` on the newly uploaded files too and set it on the directory.
5. You should **check the *mime type*** sent by the hacker. You should create a *whitelist* of allowed *mime types*. **Allow images only** if any other format is not necessary. Any other format is a security threat. Images too, but at least we have tools to handle them...
   The *corrupted content* for example: *HTML* in an image file can cause *XSS* by browsers with [*content sniffing* vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337630/what-is-x-content-type-options-nosniff). When the corrupted content is a *PHP* code, then it can be combined with an *eval injection* vulnerability.

   ```
   $userContent = '../uploads/malicious.jpg';
   include('includes/'.$userContent);
   ```

   Try to avoid this, for example use a `class autoloader` instead of including php files manually...
   By handling the *javascript injection* at first you have to **turn off *xss* and *content sniffing* in the browsers**. *Content sniffing* problems are typical by older *msie*, I think the other browsers filter them pretty well. Anyways you can prevent these problems with a bunch of headers. (Not fully supported by every browser, but that's the best you can do on client side.)

   ```
   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age={your-max-age}
   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   X-Frame-Options: deny
   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
   Content-Security-Policy: {your-security-policy}
   ```

   You can check if a file is corrupted with [`Imagick identify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.identifyimage.php), but that does not mean a complete protection.

   ```
   try {
       $uploadedImage = new Imagick($uploadedFile);
       $attributes = $uploadedImage->identifyImage();
       $format = $image->getImageFormat();
       var_dump($attributes, $format);
   } catch (ImagickException $exception) {
       //handle damaged or corrupted images
   }
   ```

   If you want to serve **other *mime types*, you should always *force download*** by them, never *include* them into webpages, unless you really know what you are doing...

   ```
   X-Download-Options: noopen
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=untrustedfile.html
   ```
6. It is possible to have valid image files with code inside them, for example in *exif* data. So you have to **purge *exif* from images**, if its content is not important to you. You can do that with *`Imagick`* or *`GD`*, but both of them requires repacking of the file. You can find an *`exiftool`* as an alternative.
   I think the simplest way to clear *exif*, is loading images with *GD*, and [save them as *PNG* with highest quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531457/php-clear-png-metadata-but-keep-similar-quality). So the images won't lose quality, and the *exif* tag will be purged, because *GD* cannot handle it. Make this with images uploaded as *PNG* too...
   If you want to extract the *exif* data, never use `preg_replace()` if the `pattern` or `replacement` is from the user, because that will lead to an *eval injection*... Use `preg_replace_callback()` instead of the `eval regex flag`, if necessary. (Common mistake in copy paste codes.) 
   *Exif* data can be a problem if your site has an *eval injection* vulnerability, for example if you use `include($userInput)` somewhere.
7. **Never ever use `include()`, `require()` by uploaded files**, serve them as static or use `file_get_contents()` or `readfile()`, or any other file reading function, if you want to control access.
   It is rarely available, but I think the best approach to use the `X-Sendfile: {filename}` headers with the [sendfile apache module](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/). By the headers, never use user input without validation or sanitization, because that will lead to *HTTP header injection*.
   If you don't need *access control* (means: only authorized users can see the uploaded files), then serve the files with your webserver. It is much faster...
8. **Use an antivir** to check the uploaded files, if you have one.
9. Always **use a combined protection**, not just a single approach. It will be harder to breach your defenses...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I forgot about this post but you made some good suggestions I'll remember for the future.

Comment: @inf3rno ,can u send me a link to a guided example which shows all the features mentioned implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Use and configure [Hardened-PHP](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/a_feature_list.html) create a plain script using [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) and the [$_FILES superglobal](http://es.php.net/features.file-upload). The simplest the script, the safest it will be (at least, as safe as the running PHP version itself)

Comment: hardened-php.net in unavailable, current page of Hardened-PHP https://www.cloudlinux.com/hardenedphp