# Php - clear PNG metadata but keep similar quality

Tags: php, image, security, file-upload

I want to convert every uploaded image to png. I think gd is a good approach for that, because it drops the metadata of the images, and does not try to parse it. I read that ImageMagick maybe has malware vulnerability on some linux servers...

I have 2 questions:

1. Does gd drop the PNG metadata too if the original file was PNG, or should I use pngcrush after converting?
2. Do I have the same quality loss as by saving JPEG files, or is the PNG format much better?

Comment: You just need a specialized PNG library or commandline tool that does not re-encode the image data. Same for JPEG. This is *not* possible with the GD library (that should answer your question already: use pngcrush).

Comment: saving as jpeg you loose quality, but file size becomes smaller, with png you do not loose quality.

Comment: comment are controversal :S
@hakre so reencoding a png file drops image quality too? is this sure?

Comment: @hakre "PNG is a lossless compression format for transmitting a single bitmap image over computer networks." So if I load every image with GD and save them as PNG they won't lose quality....

Comment: @inf3rno: gd will re-encode the image which is waste. also you don't have well control about image format specifics, be it PNG or JPG.

Comment: @hakre: What waste, what control about image format? Can you explain me? I don't understand... :S

Comment: Waste in the meaning of decoding the image data and consuming the memory of the uncompressed bitmap only to encode it again. pngcrush does not decode the image-data and it allows you to more specifically control which parts to remove.

Comment: Thanks! In my current project I can afford reencoding image data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would open the png in PHP, copy it to a new resource, then save it at full quality (in PNG, JPEG will lose quality) it will do what you want.